# Building Android application on OpenShift Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, openshift

My attempts to build an Android application with Jenkins on OpenShift failed so far.

I tried to use the android-emulator-plugin for Jenkins which should install all Android prerequisites, but it fails to download files (, probably because I should force HTTP, which is not supported by the plugin right now).

There are several question in the retired OpenShift forum, which stayed unanswered:

- [Android SDK. Jenkins.](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/android-sdk-jenkins)
- [Android build with Jenkins](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/android-build-with-jenkins)
- [Jenkins Android SDK](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/jenkins-android-sdk)

**Is it possible to build an Android application on OpenShift Jenkins? How?**

Comment: Hi Christian, I too am suffering and thinking the whole idea of running a full-blown Jenkins instance on an OpenShift gear is a bit of a fantasy at present. Here is as far as I've got (output from jenkins build) - http://pastebin.com/z6ZUV3L4 - any ideas? I think I need to be able to configure Jake Wharton's SDK Manager tool to use HTTP also...no luck just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I have opened a feature request for a Openshift Jenkins Cartridge including the Android SDK, please vote for it here: https://openshift.uservoice.com/forums/258655-ideas/suggestions/10128225-include-use-of-android-sdk-in-jenkins-catridge
I hope this will bring us closer to being able to build Android on OpenShift Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of the plugin I was able to install and download the SDK artifacts but then get stuck trying to write to the `~/.android` folder as OpenShift apparently doesn't allow writing to the user home folder (but instead need to install it under `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`).

What I did to work around that was drop to SSH and run the installation commands (i.e.: `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/tools/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk -u -a -t platform-tool` by hand on the box after switching `HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.

Comment: Did you succeded to complete a jenkins job with this ? I tryed to launch ones to build an .apk with gradle but I reacedh a disk quota exceeced in openshift

Comment: had the same problem, but it's not working for me (setting the user home folder)

Answer (score 1):

There is now something like that called Aerogear Digger.

https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-digger

https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-digger-installer

https://github.com/aerogear/digger-android-slave-image

It's an open source project and you can find there also links to mailing lists and IRC.